# SQL - Get average for multiple, but not all, rows of joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the rounded average rating for each trades person using ROUND(AVG(travisor_review.rating)). However this is returning the average for all reviews and only returning one row, when there should be a row for each trades person and the average for that trades person only. My query is below (I hope you can infer table structure from that).

```
SELECT travisor_tradesperson.name, travisor_catagory.catname, 
  travisor_city.cityname, travisor_company.cname, 
  travisor_company.description, ROUND(AVG(travisor_review.rating))
FROM `travisor_tradesperson`
INNER JOIN travisor_company 
ON travisor_tradesperson.company = travisor_company.id
INNER JOIN travisor_catagory 
ON travisor_tradesperson.catagory = travisor_catagory.id    
INNER JOIN travisor_city 
ON travisor_tradesperson.city = travisor_city.id    
INNER JOIN travisor_review 
ON travisor_review.tradesperson = travisor_tradesperson.id 
WHERE travisor_catagory.catname = '$catagory'
AND travisor_city.cityname = '$city'
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an aggregation

```
SELECT travisor_tradesperson.name, travisor_catagory.catname, 
travisor_city.cityname, travisor_company.cname, 
travisor_company.description, ROUND(AVG(travisor_review.rating))
FROM `travisor_tradesperson`
INNER JOIN travisor_company 
ON travisor_tradesperson.company = travisor_company.id
INNER JOIN travisor_catagory 
ON travisor_tradesperson.catagory = travisor_catagory.id    
INNER JOIN travisor_city 
ON travisor_tradesperson.city = travisor_city.id    
INNER JOIN travisor_review 
ON travisor_review.tradesperson = travisor_tradesperson.id 
WHERE travisor_catagory.catname = '$catagory'
AND travisor_city.cityname = '$city'
group by travisor_tradesperson.name, travisor_catagory.catname, 
travisor_city.cityname, travisor_company.cname, 
travisor_company.description
```